# Getting backendError 500 when using the webmaster.searchanalytics api for Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api

I'm getting the following error when trying to use the webmaster.searchanalytics api:

```
{ Error: Backend Error
    at Request._callback (/home/tom/Programming/MagpieMicroService/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:85:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/tom/Programming/MagpieMicroService/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/tom/Programming/MagpieMicroService/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/tom/Programming/MagpieMicroService/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
  code: 500,
  errors: 
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'backendError',
       message: 'Backend Error' } ] }
```

Code is the following:

```
'use strict';

var google = require('googleapis');
var fs = require('fs');
var key = require('./client_secret.json');
var prompt = require('prompt');

var tokens_file = './tokens/tokens.json';
var scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters'
];

var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(
    key.installed.client_id,
    key.installed.client_secret,
    key.installed.redirect_uris[0],
);



fs.readFile(tokens_file, 'utf8', (err, data)=>{
    if (err) {
        console.log('No token file: ',err);
        var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: 'offline',
            scope: scopes,
        });
        console.log(
            'Head to the URL ', 
            url, 
            ' and paste the authorization code in:'
        );
        prompt.start();
        prompt.get(['authorizationCode'],(err, result)=>{
            if (err) {return console.log(err);}
            var code = result.authorizationCode;
            oauth2Client.getToken(code, (err, tokens)=>{
                if (err) {return console.log(err);}
                console.log(tokens)
                fs.writeFile(
                    tokens_file, 
                    JSON.stringify(tokens), 
                    (err)=>{
                        if (err) {return console.log('Error ', err);}
                        console.log('Tokens Saved')
                    }
                );
                oauth2Client.setCredentials({
                    access_token: tokens.access_token,
                    refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token
                });
                //Make the authorised call here
                const webmasters = google.webmasters('v3');
                let date = new Date();
                let startDate = new Date(date-7);
                let endDate = new Date(date-7);
                let params = {
                    'startDate': "2017-09-25",//startDate.toISOString(),
                    'endDate': "2017-09-26",//endDate.toISOString(),
                    'dimensions': ['query', 'device'],
                    'rowLimit': 5000,
                    'startRow': 0,
                    'siteUrl': encodeURIComponent('http://www.url.com/de/'),
                    'auth': oauth2Client,
                };
                console.log(params.siteUrl);
                console.log(params);
                webmasters.searchanalytics.query(params,function(err, data){
                    if (err) return console.log('There was an error: ', err);
                    console.log('This is the data: ', data);
                });
            });

        });
        return;
    };
    console.log('onfile')
    var tokens = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('tokens: ', tokens);
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
        access_token: tokens.access_token,
        refresh_token: tokens.refresh_token
    });
    console.log(oauth2Client)
    //Make the authorised call here
    // google.options({auth:oauth2Client});
    const webmasters = google.webmasters('v3');
    let date = new Date();
    let startDate = new Date(date-7);
    let endDate = new Date(date-7);
    let params = {
        'startDate': "2017-09-25",//startDate.toISOString(),
        'endDate': "2017-09-26",//endDate.toISOString(),
        'dimensions': ['query', 'device'],        
        'rowLimit': 5000,
        'startRow': 0,
        'siteUrl': encodeURIComponent('http://www.url.com/de/'),
        'auth': oauth2Client,
    };
    console.log(params.siteUrl);
    console.log(params);
    webmasters.searchanalytics.query(params,function(err, data){
        if (err) return console.log('There was an error: ', err);
        console.log('This is the data: ', data);
    });
});
```

I don't see anything that I'm doing wrong. I've had bugs in the google auth api so thought it could be that. I'm using node 5.0 and all of the auth stuff seems to be working fine and returning the correct keys. The tokens save after verification but the oauth framework doesn't seem to work.